# How to transfer blob from one storage account to another storage account directly without downloading first in memory?

Tags: azure, webapi

I want to transfer blob from one storage account to another storage account in C# web API directly without downloading first in memory?

I don't want the cost for downloading first then upload again in another storage account.

I just want to transfer blob from one storage account to another storage account without applying extra cost.

Answer (score 2):

[AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10) is what you want most of the time. It is designed to do exactly what you need, and can be called via C#. Here is a [full sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-data-movement-library) for copying a blob to another storage account via C#.

You use the BlobStorage SDKs as you usually would, and in the end just copy the blobs like so:

```cs
await TransferManager.CopyAsync(sourceBlob, destinationBlob, true, null, context, cancellationSource.Token);
```

Full source code: https://github.com/azure-samples/storage-dotnet-data-movement-library-app

Comment: +1 from me, it's using the new-ish APIs for server-side copying hinted upon in my answer (which I haven't looked into fully before), this is probably better suited for you than Data Factory.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

It's worthwhile mentioning that you are only charged for bandwidth costs if you move data outside of the Azure Region if both of your blob storage accounts are within the same region you do not incur egress charges*.

[Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/introduction) is Azure's prescribed mechanism for moving data, by default it's data movement mechanism runs in the region closest to the destination. It has a c# SDK to trigger data movement. This is not free, but the cost is minimal.

Alternatively, for something simpler, an Azure Logic App could be used, which has connectors for storage accounts, however, Azure Data Factory is *made* for data movement. Basically any offering which runs within an Azure region will limit your egress costs.

Another quite compelling option is new-ish storage API which allows cross storage account copying done server-side: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/new-copy-apis-for-efficient-data-copy/ I haven't made use of this myself, as I normally require the more advanced features of Azure Data Factory, but it does sound pretty fitting for you to explore more.

It's always worthwhile proving out any PAYG operation as a proof of concept and monitoring costs prior to doing anything in production - to avoid surprises!